# Hibernate + Lucene - wildard search returning empty result

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have written article about nice Hibernate search to search database tables by wildcards.

So I have added it to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

set directory provider:

```
properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "ram");
```

and defined indexes on my entity to be visible for search mechanism:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOM_ENTITY")
@Audited
@Indexed
public class CustomEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME1", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String name1;

    @Column(name = "NAME2", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String name2;

    @Column(name = "NAME3", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String name3;

    // ...
}
```

Then I loaded manually from SQL script database table - CUSTOM_ENTITY:

```
ID |NAME1 |NAME2 |NAME3 |
-------------------------
1  |Test1 |Test1 |Test1 |
2  |Test2 |Test2 |Test2 |
3  |Test3 |Test2 |Test2 |
```

and run code in my repository:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

QueryBuilder qBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CustomEntity.class).get();

Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test").createQuery();
// Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test*").createQuery();
// Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test%").createQuery();

List test = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CustomEntity.class).getResultList();
```

However each time result collection is empty. Do you know if I missed any step? Should I load data with Hibernate API instead of SQL scripts?

---

EDIT

Befor running query I am indexing data manually:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
try {
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
QueryBuilder qBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CustomEntity.class).get();

Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test").createQuery();
// Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test*").createQuery();
// Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test%").createQuery();

List test = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CustomEntity.class).getResultList();
```

Result is still the same.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you do the [indexing](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#indexing) before [searching](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#searching) ? Your annotations look good and they should detect automatically new entities inserted  and index them. However, for existing data, you need to launch the mass indexer to rebuild the index.

Comment: Also remember that when you use the "ram" directory, your index is not persisted. Are you restarting the Hibernate SessionFactory (or JPA EntityManager) between indexing and queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved. Issue was related to the camel case "search string".

I noticed that even if I have values stored in database like:

```
ID |NAME1 |NAME2 |NAME3 |
-------------------------
1  |Test1 |Test1 |Test1 |
2  |Test2 |Test2 |Test2 |
3  |Test3 |Test2 |Test2 |
```

Lucene is not able to search by string Test*:

```
Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("Test*").createQuery();
```

When I changed my query to this:

```
Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onFields("name1", "name2", "name3").matching("test*").createQuery();
```

Everything is working fine. I do not know yet why, but it fixed the issue.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your data using SQL, you need to index the data manually using the Mass indexer. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer .

If you're using the Hibernate API, they will be indexed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After [having indexed](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) all the entities before searching, you need a correct wildcard query with `?` or `*`. The character `?` represents a single character and `*` represents any character sequence:

Assume that you've the below table :

```
ID | NAME1  | NAME2  | NAME3  |
-------------------------------
1  | test1  | test1  | test1  |
2  | test2  | test2  | test2  |
3  | test3  | test3  | test3  |
4  | test4A | test4B | test4C |
```

Then with `?` you'll obtain 3 results and with `*` you'll obtain 4 results.

```
Query luceneQuery = qBuilder.keyword()
    .wildcard()
    .onFields("name1", "name2", "name3")
    .matching("test?")  // return {1, 2, 3}
//  .matching("test*")  // return {1, 2, 3, 4}
//  .matching("test")   // return {}
    .createQuery();
```